# Facebook share: preview window is empty first time Share is clicked

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have a Share button (image) on my website. When it is clicked, the following js creates the share preview:

```
window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=www.mysite.com/thepage/', 'facebook-share-dialog', 'width=626,height=436');
```

The first time that the Share button is clicked on a page, the preview is blank. It does not even display the url. If the share window is closed, and the Share button is clicked a second time, then it works fine.

The pages are user generated so it is not possible to go through each page and make sure that each Share button has been clicked once, nor can each page be put through the linter.

Comment: this issue is happening to me too - my js pops up the window with the correct url, but the content of the window only shows an empty share block. if i then navigate to that url, or click the share link again, the content displays appropriately

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and found the solution in Facebook's documentation:

> Use og:image:width and og:image:height Open Graph tags
>
> Using these tags will specify the image to the crawler so that it can
>   render it immediately without having to asynchronously.

Just make sure your open graph tags include width and height, as well as image source. Your meta tags should look like this:

```html
<meta property="og:image" content="...image.jpg" />
<meta property="og:image:width" content="500" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="600" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Becouse **sharer.php** is a bit bugy and deprecated. I suggest to use **FB.ui** insted. Ofcourse you must create an **App** on [developers.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/)

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : "xxxxxxx", // App ID
            channelUrl : "YOURDOMAIN/channel.html", // Channel File
            status     : true, // check login status
            cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
        });
};
function isEmpty(obj) {
    for(var prop in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

// Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d){
        var js, id = "facebook-jssdk", ref = d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement("script"); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));

function shareOnWall()
{   
    FB.ui({
        method: "feed",
        link: "www.mysite.com/thepage/", //your site
        picture: "www.mysite.com/thepage/images/someimage.png",
        name: "Some Name",
        caption: "blah blah",
        description: "Message"
    }, shareCallback);
}

function shareCallback(response)
{
    //share was successful
}
```

Here is the code and good luck. ;)